# unable to export Json data from HDFS to Oracle using sqoop export

Tags: json, oracle, sqoop

while doing sqoop export,cant parse input data.seeing below exception.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '"DeptId":888'

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException

From Oracle DeptId is Number datatype

sqoop export \
--connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=wcx2-scan.***.com)(PORT=***))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=***)))" \
--table API.CUSTOMER \
--columns 'Id','DeptId','Strategy','RCM_PROD_MSG_TXT' \
--export-dir /tmp/test \
--map-column-java RCM_PROD_MSG_TXT=String \
--username ********* \
--password ********** \
--input-fields-terminated-by ',' \
--input-null-string '\N'  \
--input-null-non-string '\N'

Sample Json data

{"Id":"27952436","DeptId":888,"Strategy":"syn-cat-recs","recs": 
[629848,1029280]}

Make sure data should be loaded to Oracle table